# No Wifi settings available in Windows 11 (Windows to go)

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-11

I installed Windows 11 on a USB key (Windows to go) by Hasleo Win2USB on Macbook pro.

Once I booted into Windows 11, no wifi & wifi settings were available.

I re-installed Windows 11 inside the system and rebooted it, wifi did not show up.

I installed wifi driver for Windows 11: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19351/windows-10-and-windows-11-wi-fi-drivers-for-intel-wireless-adapters.html, and rebooted the system, still to no avail.

Would it be possible to fix it?

In Disk Manager, Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet was shown to work normally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need the Boot Camp drivers - [Apple KB - Download and install Windows support software on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204923)

You need to start this process from the Mac, not Windows. I'm really not sure how it will behave on a Win2Go install, as not even Microsoft support those on a PC any more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would it be possible to start bootcamp in Internet recovery mode for Macbook? Or do I have to install Mac OS and start bootcamp from Application - Utilities? Windows is already installed on the internal hard drive, and in Internet recovery mode of Mavericks, under "Utilities", no bootcamp is available.

Comment: You need a full running macOS to have the Boot Camp Assistant & be able to run it.

Comment: I just realised you said Mavericks. No Mac of that age [2007-2009] is qualified to run Win 10 or 11. There are no drivers for Windows for hardware that old. 2015 is about the break point for even basic driver support. The 'trick' for Win 10 was to install Win7, which *is* supported, then run 10 as an update. That way *some* of the older drivers would possibly continue to work. I'm not sure that method would still work for even Win 10 after 2021, as MS was dropping support even for 2015 models.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Windows 11 is actually now installed on this Macbook Pro. I used a USB Key to get Mac OS installed on it for bootcamp assistant. Once Macbook pro booted into Internet recovery (on this USB key), it appeared to be Marvericks.

Comment: It would be best if we knew exactly which Mac, & which OS. You might squeeze a Windows OS onto a machine, but still not be able to get hold of drivers appropriate to it.